# Biot-Savart law on an exponential spiral

Tags: integration, physics, electromagnetism

> A wire carrying a current $I$ is bent into the shape of an exponential spiral, $r = e^θ$, from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 2\pi$ as shown in the figure below. 
> To complete a loop, the ends of the spiral are connected by a straight wire at the origin along the x axis. Find the magnitude $G$ and direction of the magnetic field $B$.
> Hint: Use the Biot–Savart law. The
> angle $\beta$ between a radial line and its
> tangent line at any point on the curve $r$
> = $f (θ)$ is related to the function in the
> following way:
> $tan β = \frac{r}{\frac{dr}{d\theta}}$.

The answer and how to do it can be found here at page 7:
[Full question](https://ocw.aprende.org/courses/physics/8-02sc-physics-ii-electricity-and-magnetism-fall-2010/creating-magnetic-fields/biot-savart-law/MIT8_02SC_challenge_sol19.pdf)

The thing is that I solved it a different way and came to the same solution. I first changed the coordinate system into polar coordinates. So the vector along the spiral can be written as: $L = (r\cos(θ),r\sin(θ),0) = (e^θ\cos(θ),e^θ\sin(θ)).$

After calculating the cross product and the norm of $-L$, using Biot-Savart I was able to come to the same solution as the one shown in the question. But this only holds if I don't use the Jacobian determinant for polar coordinates which is $r = e^θ$. So,my question is am I doing it wrong, do we need the Jacobian determinant when changing to polar coordinates for the law of Biot-Savart?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that here you are integrating over a curve, so you aren't changing the coordinate system so much as you are just parameterizing the curve. So no Jacobian should be necessary.

Comment: Oh ok, so whenever you are integrating over a curve you don't need the Jacobian. Thanks a lot